# PHP - Assign variable and use it to assign value to array all in one step

Tags: php

I've this `config.php` file that contains this example array:

```
return [
  myarray => [
    'foo' => 'bar_'.str_random(5).'.log'
  ]
]
```

I'd like to assign the `str_random(5)` into a `$var` variable and use it all in one step; for example, something like (**this example doesn't work**):

```
return [
  myarray = [
    'foo' => 'bar_'.(($var=str_random(5)) && $var).'.log'
  ]
]
```

The output should be:

```
echo $var;
uoEUu

print_r($myarray);
[
  'foo' => 'bar_uoEUu.log'
]
```

Thank you

---

**EDIT**

Ok, I found this solution, but It doesn't like me:

```
return [
  myarray = [
    'foo' => 'bar_'.$var=str_random(5).''.$var.'.log'
  ]
]
```

any cleaner suggestions?

Comment: Why? You could set `$var` before creating the array and just use it in the array.

Comment: This content is in a config file; and this array is returned: 
`return [
   myarray = [
      'foo' => 'bar_'.(($var=str_random(5)) && $var).'.log'
   ]
]
`

Comment: There is no reason I can see why you'd want to do this all in one step, and depending on what `str_random` is / does, the `&& $var` may be unneeded, and is the bit that means that $var is a boolean, so you're concat-ing a bool to a string which appears to not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in brackets:

```
$myarray = [
  'foo' => 'bar_'.($var=uniqid()).'.log'
]

var_dump($var, $myarray);
```

Which gives you :

```
string(13) "5d2f1f1e01338" 
array(1) { ["foo"]=> string(34) "bar_5d2f1f1e01338.log" }
```

Check it out here: https://3v4l.org/JfZf6

Comment: This doesn't quite match the desired output, as the random string gets inserted twice.

Comment: His code wanted 2? (based on his updated question) `'bar_'.($var=uniqid()).''.$var.'.log'` the only bit i changed was `uniqid()`, as the function he uses is a custom one

Comment: The desired output shows just one instance of the random string: `bar_uoEUu.log`. The duplication seems to just be a mistake in trying to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually much simpler than you think:

```
$myarray = [
  'foo' => 'bar_'.($var=str_random(5)).'.log'
];
```

The reason this works is that any assignment can be used as an *expression* whose value is the value assigned. This isn't often necessary, but has a few uses, like setting multiple variables to the same value:

```
$foo = $bar = 42;
```

In this case, you're concatenating a fixed string, an expression (which happens to be an assignment), and another fixed string; the extra parentheses just make sure that the assignment expression is evaluated before the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you are overthinking the problem. If you need to use `$var` after assigning it to `foo` you can just do the following:

```
$var = str_random(5);
$myarray = [
  'foo' => "bar_$var.log"
];
```

Comment: As clarified in comments, this is a simplified example, which comes in the middle of a larger block of code in a config file. While unusual, I can imagine scenarios where this is useful.